# Qt - Evaluate my QThread approach. Deleting part crashes

Tags: qt, qthread

I use QThread in a very different way I'm used to see.
Take a look:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class CustomWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomWorker()
    {
        _thread = new QThread();
        this->moveToThread(_thread);
        _thread->start();

        connect(_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(threadFinished()));

        connect(this, SIGNAL(process1Signal()), this, SLOT(process1Slot()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(process2Signal()), this, SLOT(process2Slot()));
    }

    void deleteMe()
    {
        _thread->quit();
    }

public:
    void process1(){ emit process1Signal(); }
    void process2(){ emit process2Signal(); }

signals:
    void process1Signal();
    void process2Signal();

private slots:
    void process1Slot(){ /* code to run in background */ }
    void process2Slot(){ /* code to run in background */ }

    void threadFinished()
    {
        _thread->deleteLater();
        this->deleteLater();
    }

private:
    QThread* _thread;
};
```

So, I can use the CustomWorker calling the functions process1() or process2() directly:

```
_worker = new CustomWorker;
connect(_worker, SIGNAL(process1Ended()), this, SLOT(handleProcess1()));
connect(_worker, SIGNAL(process2Ended()), this, SLOT(handleProcess2()));
...
_worker->process1();
```

It's working fine... But the delete part sometimes crashes:

```
_worker->deleteMe();
```

And I don't know what's happening. What would be the correct way to implement it?

PS: I use macros to create the signals and slots, so I don't type too much like that.

Comment: Any reason you're allocating the `QThread` on the heap in the first place?

Comment: No... I came from Java, where all objects live on heap. Would be better if I had just a QThread member class without a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you might be deleting a thread before it is finished. So change your `deleteMe()` method as below:

```
void deleteMe()
{
    _thread->quit();
    _thread->wait();  // just add this line
}
```

And deleting object inside the class is not recommended.

**Note** that OP is already using `deleteLater`, otherwise, in many cases Qt's `QThread` class needs `deleteLater()` instead of `delete` for owned QObject(s), or else it will crash.

That is the case even if you `delete` the `QThread` itself: hence it should be `myThreadPtr->deleteLater()`.

Basically, treat it like the `QThread` is yet running even if it is NOT.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is thread affinity; which thread an object is running. Note that `QThread` is not actually a thread, but more like a thread controller.

```
class CustomWorker : public QObject
{
public:
    CustomWorker()
    {
        _thread = new QThread();
        this->moveToThread(_thread);
    }

private:
   QThread* _thread
};

_worker = new CustomWorker;
```

Let's say a `CustomWorker` object is instantiated on the main (gui) thread. Its constructor creates the `QThread` member instance, which is also on the main thread.

Following the call to `moveToThread(_thread)`, the `_worker` object has now been moved to the new thread. The thread instance `_thread` is not a child of the `CustomWorker` class, so it remains on the main thread. When delete is called, you're now trying to delete the `QThread` object, which resides on a different thread to the object you're deleting.

To fix this, move the QThread out of the CustomerWorker class. The only association a thread should have to the objects that run on them, is via the moveToThread function.

Consider that your design should allow for one QThread object and multiple worker instances that can run on that one thread.

For more info about about `QThread`, I recommend reading [this blog post](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).